# Selecionar Lote Ativo

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou estudando sobre consultas no SQLServer e tenho o seguinte cenário:

Tenho uma tabela de lote que possui os seguintes campos:

Tabela de Lote (Lot)

```
Id INT  
ProdutoID INT  
Preco SMALLMONEY  
Inicio DATETIME  
Fim DATETIME
```

Tabela de Produtos (Products)

```
Id INT  
Name VARCHAR  
Tipo INT
```

Tabela de Tipos (Types)

```
Id INT  
Name VARCHAR
```

OBS.: E uma tabela bem resumida e de exemplo

Preciso realizar um consulta que me dê o Preço atual do produto. Ex.:

Types

```
Id | Name
01 | Teste  
02 | Testando
```

Produtos

```
Id | Name    | Tipo
01 | Celular | 01  
02 | Câmera  | 02
```

Lotes

```
Id | ProdutoId | Preco | Inicio                  | Fim  
1  |         1 |    50 | 2017-08-14 13:10:57.980 | 2017-08-16 13:10:57.980
2  |         1 |   100 | 2017-08-12 13:10:57.980 | NULL
```

Como podem ver, Lotes possui 2 Registros o registro com <kbd>NULL</kbd> é o preço oficial do produto e o primeiro registro é uma promoção que começa no dia 14 e termina no dia 16. Levando em consideração que a data de publicação desta pergunta é 15/08 o preço atual seria de 50.

Como faço a query para selecionar Nome do produto, Tipo do produto e o preço atual? (Levando em consideração a data da promoção)

OBS.: Caso deve funcionar também com estes registros:

```
Id | ProdutoId | Preco | Inicio                  | Fim  
1  |         1 |    50 | 2017-08-14 13:10:57.980 | 2017-08-16 13:10:57.980
2  |         1 |   100 | 2017-08-12 13:10:57.980 | NULL
3  |         1 |   150 | 2017-08-17 13:10:57.980 | NULL
```

Neste caso, o valor daquele produto vai aumentar no dia 17.

Só para não ficar em branco, estou fazendo a segunda consulta:

```sql
select p.Nome as 'Produto', t.Nome as 'Tipo', l.Preco, MAX(p.Inicio)
from Lote as l inner join Produtos as p on l.ProdutoId = p.Id
inner join Tipos as t on p.TipoId = t.Id
group by p.Nome, t.Nome, l.preco
```

Porém não funciona da forma correta obviamente, agradeço desde já!

Comment: Recebi menos um, mas nenhum comentário do que está errado com minha pergunta :/ Como eu poderia melhora-la para ajudar na comunidade?

Comment: As colunas Inicio e Fim estão declaradas como `datetime`. Elas contêm somente data ou contêm data e horário?

Comment: @JoséDiz as contem data e hora.

Comment: Poderia alterar os exemplos, acrescentando a parte de horário? É para reavaliar a proposta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eis sugestão que utiliza a tabela de produtos como ponto de partida.

```
-- código #1 v3
declare @Hoje datetime;
set @Hoje= cast(current_timestamp as date);

--
with ctePreços as (
SELECT P.Id, P.Name, T.Name as Tipo, 
       (SELECT top (1) Preco 
          from Lot as L1 
          where L1.ProdutoId = P.Id
                and L1.Fim is NULL
                and @Hoje >= L1.Inicio 
          order by L1.Inicio desc) as Oficial,
       (SELECT Preco 
          from Lot as L2 
          where L2.ProdutoId = P.Id
                and @Hoje between L2.Inicio and L2.Fim) as Oferta
  from Products as P
       inner join Types as T on T.Id = P.Tipo
)
SELECT Id, 
       Name as [Nome do produto], 
       Tipo as [Tipo de produto],
       coalesce(Oferta, Oficial) as [Preço atual]
  from ctePreços;
```

---

Eis outra abordagem, que utiliza a tabela de lotes como ponto de partida. Neste caso, somente são listados os produtos que tenham informação na tabela Lot.

```
-- código #2
declare @Hoje datetime;
set @Hoje= cast(current_timestamp as date);

--
with cteAtual as (
SELECT L.*,
       Seq= row_number() over (partition by L.ProdutoId order by L.Inicio desc)
  from Lot as L
  where L.Inicio <= @Hoje
        and (L.Fim is NULL or L.Fim >= @Hoje)
)
SELECT A.ProdutoId, 
       P.Name as [Nome do produto], 
       T.Name as [Tipo de produto],
       A.Preco as [Preço atual]
  from cteAtual as A
       inner join Products as P on P.Id = A.ProdutoId
       inner join Types as T on T.Id = P.Tipo
  where A.Seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que a query seguinte resolva seu problema:
Não coloquei os tipos pois é irrelevante ao problema, basta ser adicionado,
e apenas uma questão de nomes, acredito que lote não seja o nome correto para esta tabela. Um lote deve ter uma identificação, data de fabricação e validade. Essa tabela me parece mais com uma tabela de preços.

```
Select distinct
    p.nome,
    coalesce(lp.preco, l.preco,0) as preco
from produtos p 
left outer join lote lp on lp.produtoid = p.id 
                        and lp.id = (select 
                                        max(x.id) 
                                     from lote x 
                                     where x.produtoid = lp.produtoid 
                                     and x.inicio <= getdate() 
                                     and x.fim >= getdate())
left outer join lote l on l.produtoid = p.id 
                       and l.inicio <= getdate() 
                       and l.fim is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a expressão `WITH` para priorizar os preços juntamente com a função `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH Prices (Id,
             ProdutoID,
             Preco,
             Inicio,
             Fim,
             Prioridade)
AS (
  SELECT lot.Id,
         lot.ProdutoID,
         lot.Preco,
         lot.Inicio,
         lot.Fim,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY lot.ProdutoID ORDER BY lot.Inicio) AS Prioridade
    FROM Lot lot
   WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN lot.Inicio AND ISNULL(lot.Fim, GETDATE())
)
SELECT prod.Name  AS 'Nome do Produto',
       type.Name  AS 'Tipo do produto',
       pric.Preco AS 'Preço atual'
  FROM Products prod
       INNER JOIN Types type ON type.Id = prod.Tipo
       INNER JOIN Prices pric ON pric.ProdutoID = prod.Id
 WHERE pric.Prioridade = 1;
```

Comment: O responsável pelo `downvote` poderia dizer qual o problema que deve ser corrigido nesta resposta que justifica essa votação?